# Face Recognition using javaCV and netbeans

Tags: java, image-processing, netbeans, opencv3.0, javacv

Application should be able to save images face_1_01.png , face_1_02.png , face_2_01.png and so on in a folder called training images using a webcam, then application should be able to loop through all the images in that folder and recognize the face/faces currently appearing in the webcam returning the name of the image above the rectangle that is drawn over the face.

[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxXeOSFkKUs) is an example. Unfortunately the application in the video is not open source..

[here](http://pcbje.github.io/misc/2012/12/01/doing-face-recognition-with-javacv.html) is the link of following code.

```
    import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FilenameFilter;

    public class OpenCVFaceRecognizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String trainingDir = args[0];
    IplImage testImage = cvLoadImage(args[1]);

    File root = new File(trainingDir);

    FilenameFilter pngFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png");
        }
    };

    File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

    MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

    int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];

    int counter = 0;
    int label;

    IplImage img;
    IplImage grayImg;

    for (File image : imageFiles) {
        img = cvLoadImage(image.getAbsolutePath());

        label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("\\-")[0]);

        grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        images.put(counter, grayImg);

        labels[counter] = label;

        counter++;
    }

    IplImage greyTestImage = IplImage.create(testImage.width(), testImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
    // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

    faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);

    cvCvtColor(testImage, greyTestImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(greyTestImage);

    System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);
    }
    }
```

**I am unable to figure out where to specify the path name of the directory with contains all the training images.**

Answer (score 0):

`String trainingDir = args[0];`

The program read traningDir from the first command-line parameters.

You can either run via console(i.e. terminal in linux or DOS in windows) like

`java OpenCVFaceRecognizer /path/to/training/Dir`

or in IDE add /path/to/traning/Dir into "run" parameter of this project. In the latter way, you can click "run" button to execute.